# Trouble understanding Spring Boot code flow

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-boot, program-flow

I have a spring boot code like following which handles a particular mapping like following -

```
@RestController
@ResponseBody
public class SomeAPIController {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/some-api",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"}
    )

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public SomeAPIPayload validateAPIUpdate(
            @Valid @RequestParam(value = "query", defaultValue="") String queryString

    )
```

But in above code if I pass query as `"something"` it works fine but if I pass say, `"#something"` it fails to query(I verified it by printing `queryString` value, and it comes out to be empty) so, as far my understanding `@Valid`(which is imported from `javax.validation`) is doing some validation and doesn't let `"#something"` pass. I want to know how to track down the validation file or if something other is wrong how to locate it ?
Any pointers in direction will be extremely helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything following a hash (`#`) is interpreted as anchor/fragment and will not be sent to the server as stated in RFC 1738.
To send a hash symbol, you need to encode it as `%23`.

Comment: `%23` I think in place of `#23` :P

Comment: @Vimal Good spot.

Answer (score 1):

`#` in `URL` stands for a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). So if your query is `http://example.com?query=#something` then the `#something` part is considered a fragment identifier and the `query` parameter is empty.